# BASH ignore e-mail addresses that have been sent e-mail in past 24 hours

Tags: bash

I have a BASH script like the below:

```
cat limit_mail.out | while read num email limit orders; do
    echo "Sending mail to '$email'"
    printf "$email_template" "$email" "$num" "$limit" "$orders" |
    sendmail -oi -t
done
```

How can I make it so that when an e-mail is sent the e-mail address is saved with date and time in a text file, and then a check so that no e-mail address receives more than 1 e-mail within 24 hours?

Comment: You can use a temp file. Write a date inside and then check it

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko Yes this is exactly what I need but I need an example using my code on how to do it, please?

Comment: @user2656114 Care to tell us what are the emails for? Not that I really to know..

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to create a file per recipient, and use the file's timestamp.

```
MAIL_TIMESTAMPS=/var/cache/mailstamps
mkdir "$MAIL_TIMESTAMPS"

cat limit_mail.out | while read num email limit orders; do
    echo "Sending mail to '$email'"
    email_hash="$(md5sum <<< "$email" | cut -d' ' -f1)";
    # Check that a timestamp file doesn't exist, or that it was modified over 24h ago
    if ! test -n "$(find "$MAIL_TIMESTAMPS" -mtime -1 -name "$email_hash")"; then
      touch "$MAIL_TIMESTAMPS/$email_hash" # Update timestamp
      printf "$email_template" "$email" "$num" "$limit" "$orders" |
      sendmail -oi -t
    fi
done
```

**Edit:** I've added hashing of the email address. It was something I was planning to do anyway, but [Aleks-Daniel's code for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18573647/15996) is so nice and concise that I've borrowed it here, changing only from sha256sum to md5sum. MD5 is faster, and though it has potential issues I don't think they will be a problem here (of course you're free to choose). Hashing also avoids the issue of special characters upsetting find's filename matching.

Comment: I tested it using this suggested code however no e-mail is sent nor file created. A manual touch using the e-mail address and `$MAIL_TIMESTAMPS` directory I have set works ok, though. Any suggestion on this?

Comment: I updated the code, check you're using the latest version (I've tested it, and it's working for me)

Answer (score 1):

Using timestamps in a file:

```
DELAY_FOLDER='myTempFolder/'
DELAY=$((24*60*60)) # one day

while read num email limit orders; do
    echo "Sending mail to '$email'"
    if [[ -f $DELAY_FOLDER/$email ]] && (( $(cat "$DELAY_FOLDER/$email") + DELAY > $(date +%s) )); then
        echo "email has been sent already"
    else
        printf "$email_template" "$email" "$num" "$limit" "$orders" | sendmail -oi -t
        echo "$(date +%s)" > "$DELAY_FOLDER/$email"
    fi
done < limit_mail.out
```

Also, if you don't want anybody to see email addresses in a temp folder, you can use md5 or sha sums to cover your addresses. Like this:

```
DELAY_FOLDER='myTempFolder/'
DELAY=$((24*60*60)) # one day

while read num email limit orders; do
    echo "Sending mail to '$email'"
    emailsha=$(sha256sum <<< "$email" | cut -d' ' -f1)
    if [[ -f $DELAY_FOLDER/$emailsha ]] && (( $(cat "$DELAY_FOLDER/$emailsha") + DELAY > $(date +%s) )); then
        echo "email has been sent already"
    else
        printf "$email_template" "$email" "$num" "$limit" "$orders" | sendmail -oi -t
        echo "$(date +%s)" > "$DELAY_FOLDER/$emailsha"
    fi
done < limit_mail.out
```

Comment: +1 for the MD5 solution, and tangentially for avoiding the [Useless Use of `cat`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html).